# 2 Sharepoint 2010 lists. custom list(A) and a related task list(B). workflow runs on A. Can update status in list B specific item?

Tags: custom-list, custom-form

I have 2 Sharepoint 2010 lists. More specific a custom list(A) and a related task list(B). I have a workflow that runs on list A.

Within this workflow I need to create tasks assigned to different persons(so an A list item may have multiple B items). For each task that is assigned I need a custom form which I am able to do in InfoPath.

The Problem: I need to be able to give the user who completes a task the possibility to change the status for the task, (this would be the task status in B), maybe several times until he finally clicks the complete task button.

Question : what kind of action would be the best to use: collect data from user,custom task process, assign-to do, assign form. For the last 2, while trying to make a lookup for the status field in order to update it, it raises a unique field error message as it cannot identify a specific item in list B to update. Trying to use the collect data and adding a Status field to each form, it creates separate Status fields in list B which I don't want as the only one should be the initial Status field.

Custom code, is not an option. :|